# React Form onSubmit does not work. Method passed thru Context API

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-context

Method passed thru Context Api, works fine inside button onClick method ( inside the same form ) ,
but does not work inside form onSubmit method.

Gdpr.js

```
render() {

    return (
        <MyContext.Consumer>
            {(context) => (
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={context.onSubmitGdpr}>

                        <FormattedMessage id='app.terms'/>
                        <div>
                            <label className="container"><strong><FormattedMessage id={"app.terms.agree"}/></strong>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.agree} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                            </label>
                            <Link to={context.state.nextStageAfterGDPR ? context.state.nextStageAfterGDPR : "#"}>
                                <button disabled={!this.state.agree}><FormattedMessage id='app.buttons.submit'/>
                                </button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
            }
        </MyContext.Consumer>
    )
}

export default Gdpr
```

MyProvider.js

Method passed through Context API provider is ...

```
onSubmitGdpr = (e) => {                                                        

    e.preventDefault()                                                         
    fetch("/api/v1/gdpr")                                                      
        .then(res=> res.json())                                                
        .then(data => { this.setState({nextStageAfterGDPR: "./camera-intro"})                                                      
        })                                                                     
        .catch(error=>console.log(error))                           
}
```

MyProvider.js continues ...

```
render() {                                                                          
    return (                                    
        <MyContext.Provider value={{            
            state: this.state,                  
            onSubmitStart: this.onSubmitStart,  
            onSubmitGdpr: this.onSubmitGdpr     
        }}>                                     
            {this.props.children}               
        </MyContext.Provider>                   
    )                                           

}
```

Comment: This means that  <button> doesn't work as you expect. Could be specific to <Link> or else. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. It seems like context API and `onSubmitGdpr ` are irrelevant, it would be the same with any function.

Comment: What user action are you doing for which you expect the `onSubmit` to execute?